# I would like a button added to the top line for favourite tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, design

I am not sure I have asked this correctly. I will try to explain what I am looking for.

Across the top of the page is the bar with `Questions`, `Tags`, `Users` etc.  I would like a button added here labeled `Favorites` that links to a list of newest questions filtered by my favorite tags.

I find myself repeating this pattern every time I log in: clicking on `Questions`, scrolling down and clicking one of my favorite tags, then repeating for each one.

For the record I realize that many people have asked for similar things before and been shot down.  I am just trying to present another way to implement this that the powers that be might be willing to implement.  The bottom line for all of these ideas is that people would like to have a one click solution to view the question for all their Favorite Tags at once.

I think this would be useful to regular users on all the Stackexchange sites.

Comment: I was thinking about this also...

Comment: This is kinda supposed to be what the homepage and/or the "interesting" tab is for.

Comment: but the interesting tab includes lots of questions which I am not interested in. (questions with no tags in my "Favourite Tags")

Comment: I would like to put this button here so it is on every page.  After answering and/or commenting on a question I would like to one click back to a list of newest question containing my favorite tags (all of them).  The closest I can find now is clicking back several times to get to my last search then hitting refresh.  If there is a reason as to why this is undesirable, I am curious to know what it is.